# Should I use inheritance if i want to reduce boiler plate codes in this scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a Pojo class that is corresponding to a table in the database. The class Report.java has several fields:

```
class Report {
   public Date createDate;
   public String creator;
   public String description;
   public String id;
}
```

From the first requirement, I need to return the Report object using the id to search for it in the database. The response should only contains those 4 fields. But now they want to have another REST endpoint such that with the id, I need to return extra information in the response such as Date validUntil; 
I am thinking to use inheritance for this such as:

```
class ExtendedReport extends Report {
  public Date validUntil;
}
```

I am not sure is this the best way to reduce boiler plate or I should do another way ?

Thank you.

Comment: In OOD, and esp. Java, inheritance should be used to denote *is-a* relationship.  As long as `ExtendedReport` *is-a* `Report`, then this is probably OK to do.  If inheriting also saves you boilerplate, that's a bonus.  If *is-a* is not approprate, consider delegation and *has-a* rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is mapping 1 to 1 the database object and you are using an [ORM](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) mapping, it is good to split the two classes and take all inheritance benefits.

As generic approach I humbly propose to subdivide Models (that maps the repository, e.g. relational database) to the View Model, that are object returned to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is separation of objects between the different layers of an application, this mean you can have a Report object that map directly to your database and yet have a different set of object that are used to communicate with the clients you can also have a third set of objects, your business object, which will contain logic that is relevant to your application. Note that you will need to maintain a logic that converts between those object maybe a builder pattern or something similar. As a small example lets consider your case, you can have:

1. Report: class with a 1 to 1 mapping to the DB, makes it easy to save and retrieve objects
2. ReportDAO: contains same fields as Report but with additional functionality that the application may use when manipulating these reports (can't think of anything now)
3. ReportDTO/ExtendedReportDTO: you can have multiple classes with inheritance or without and those will contain only fields + getters/setters and are used to communicate with the clients.

It may not be obvious now using this simple example but separating your object will make it a lot easier to extend and modify your application later on. Currently you may have the same information at all the levels but later this may change, also it is a good idea to not to expose your business object so if you're using the Report class in your application it is not a good idea to share it in an API for example. So I would say you can use inheritance here but for me at least I don't think it is a good idea to have these same objects at the level of the app and the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If both REST endpoint must return **the same** report but expose different amount of information then you may find `@JsonView` is useful.

Here is example http://rsdn.org/forum/flame.politics/7430262

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Internal extends Public {
    }
}

public class Item {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public String itemName;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String ownerName;
}


@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
@RequestMapping("/items/{id}")
public Item getItemPublic(@PathVariable int id) {
    return ItemManager.getById(id);
}

@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
@RequestMapping("/items/internal/{id}")
public Item getItemInternal(@PathVariable int id) {
    return ItemManager.getById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've learned with « Domain driven design » : don’t try to find a « silverbullet » model. There is always different ways to represent your concept. The model always depend on the context.

Here , The way your `report` is stored is one representation.
The way your REST client wants to read it is *another* representation.
 You can imagine having a representation per use-case.

In such a situation, I would not make the economy of coding the mapping between each application layer or between domain bounded contexts.

Also, i would avoid inheritance, preferring   some interface if necessary , accepting some code redundancy.